# Git status incorrectly saying files are deleted

Tags: git, git-status

I cloned a repository and edited exactly one file in it, `tip.php`, and then added it using `git add`. But when I next run `git status` I get the following:

```
$ git status
On branch removeRatings
Changes to be committed:
 (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

 deleted: .htaccess
 deleted: COPYRIGHT.txt
 modified: tip.php
```

Even though neither `.htaccess` or `COPYRIGHT.txt` was deleted, as I can see them right in the directory. Anyone have a reason why this would happen? I'm running Git Bash on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that files (or file removals) were added to stage.

Run the following commands.

```
 git add --all
 git status
```

Now you should see whether they were moved/renamed or just deleted. I suppose that they were moved in some way, maybe by your IDE.

```
git reset .htaccess
git reset COPYRIGHT.txt
git status
```

Now the status should be clear and show only your `tip.php`. But if you now see `.htaccess` and COPYRIGHT.txt` in the untracked files, then these files have been changed since the last commit.

If you're sure that you didn't change or delete them and do not want to save changes:

```
git reset --hard .htaccess
git reset --hard COPYRIGHT.txt
```

This will reset these files to the state of last commit. Be careful and don't run `git reset --hard` without an argument, as it would completely delete your uncommited changes.